# The error message "code: 'ECONNREFUSED'" indicates connection to the server

Tags: json, port

```
> evershop@1.0.0-beta start
> evershop start

WARNING: NODE_ENV value of 'production' did not match any deployment config file names.
WARNING: See https://github.com/lorenwest/node-config/wiki/Strict-Mode
WARNING: No configurations found in configuration directory:C:\Users\Kawishbhatti\Downloads\evershop-main\evershop-main\config
WARNING: To disable this warning set SUPPRESS_NO_CONFIG_WARNING in the environment.
Error: connect ECONNREFUSED ::1:5432
    at TCPConnectWrap.afterConnect [as oncomplete] (node:net:1494:16) {
  errno: -4078,
  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',
  syscall: 'connect',
  address: '::1',
  port: 5432
```

i am facing error pls any one help me

ans of my question  code: 'ECONNREFUSED',

Comment: the address you are trying to connect to is blank. Likely because no address has been configured for this environment. Which likely has to do with the `NODE_ENV value of 'production' did not match any deployment config file names.` warning you are seeing. You are trying to run your code in an environment that has no configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Look like you have a connection issue to your database. I suggest to check again the connection strings(host, username, password)